# RepositoryItemDateEdit date click event

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, devexpress-windows-ui

My RepositoryItemDateEdit is a part of a RepositoryItemCollection inside a RibbonControl

When a date is double-clicked the value change event is handled.

I want to have the date to be temporary changed in the above field when the date is clicked once.

[My Date Control]
[image]

Does anyone know if there is an event that can handle that?

I tried with click events straight from the date edit control but it seems to not render the date click itself or maybe I have done something wrong.

Logically when the date is clicked it gets a grey font background, so there has to be some sort of way to add something additional to that.

I am using DevExpress v.23.1

Comment: And what did you try so far? It's always easier to help someone when there's a code snippet to work on.